# Centering text in div while ignoring image width on same line

Tags: css, html

What I want is center text in my footer (copyright) and have my social media links in same line with the text on the right. But the problem is, that when I add e.g. facebook icon there, text is not center anymore.

What I want: https://i.gyazo.com/cce548b5b19baff5165dfac3babff244.png

What I have right now: https://i.gyazo.com/14675784e748c676b3c8a01cfe97b304.png

So how I get the text center, ignoring the width of the image so it goes really to the middle, not middle of the remaining footer after image.

Comment: there are few ways to do it, what your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a **negative margin-left to the image, equaling the width of the image**.

```css
.nav {
  background: #00A2E8;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.copright {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.side-image {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav text-center">
  <span class="copright">Copyright</span>
  <img src="http://www.emp3.ws/img.php?i=http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000126500818-m9uyre-large.jpg" alt="rocket" height="40" width="40" class='side-image' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <p>copyright</p>
  <img />
</footer
```

CSS:

```
footer {
  height:50px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 50px; /*Same height as footer*/
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right
}
```

Should Work like this. Code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

First quess is to add `float:right` to the image, but without code its hard to know what will do.